# How to get 10 days back date by giving one date as parameter to the shell script

Tags: shell

If i give the date "20130828"(not a current date) in YYYYMMDD format, how can i get 10 days back date using shell script i.e. 20130818
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
date +%Y%m%d --date="20130818 -10 day"
```

or even

```
date +%Y%m%d --date="20130818 10 days ago"
```

`+%Y%m%d` is the format of your date (YYYYmmdd), and through `--date` you can provide a string (in a very human readable format) to specify when you want this date.

Comment: @NaveenReddyCH -> Consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it satisfied your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
date --date="20130828 - 10 days" +"%Y%m%d"
```

Outputs

```
20130818
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have gnu date, you can just give `10 days ago` to date's `-d` option:

```
kent$ date -d'10 days ago 20130828' +%Y%m%d
20130818
```